# Proof that the map is an open map.

Tags: general-topology

We were asked to prove that the map $f\ :\mathbb{R}^{n+1}/{0}\longrightarrow S^{n}$ given by $f(x)\ =\ x/||x||$ is an open map.
My approach :- it is enough to show that for any $x\in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ and the open ball $B(x,R)$, $f(B(x,R))$ is open in $S^n$, i.e. $X\ =\ S^n/f(B(x,R))$ is closed.

So, let $y\in cl(X)$ where $cl(X)$ denotes the closure of $X$. Then there exist a sequence $(y_n)$ in $X$ such that $(y_n)\rightarrow y$. We need to show that $y\in X$ or $y\ =\ z/||z||$ such that $||x-z|| \geq R$. Now $(y_n)$ is in $X$ so $\forall \ n$ $y_n\ =\ z_n/||z_n||$ such that $||x-z_n||\geq R$. Since $(y_n)\rightarrow y$ so $(z_n)$ must converge to $z$ and by the continuity of the norm function $||z_n||\rightarrow ||z||$. Again, by the continuity of the norm function $||x-z||\geq R$ and hence $y\in X$ and so $X$ is closed.

My question is that what is wrong with the above proof ? What would be an alternate argument for showing that $f$ is an open map ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The convergence of the $y_n$ doesn't guarantee convergence of $z_n$, e.g. $z_n=n$ doesn't converge, but the corresponding $y_n$ sequence is constant $1$.

*Edit*: As an alternative proof you can show the following: Suppose $B(x,\delta) \subseteq U$, then $B(f(x), {\delta \over \lVert x \rVert})\cap S^n \subseteq f(U)$.

Comment: thanks, i made a mistake there...but how is $f$ a quotient map ? how are you identifying points in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$

Comment: $x$ is identified with $y$ if $y$ lies on the half line starting at $0$ going through $x$. You can easily show that this is an equivalence relation.

Comment: ya that is an equivalence relation, but not every quotient map is an open map, right?

Comment: @walcher: Are you sure that every quotient map is an open map? I think that open maps are quotient but that the opposite is not necessarily true.

Comment: You're right of course, I got my definitions mixed up. Quotient maps need not be open (I was thinking of covering maps). Anyway the  natural way to prove that $f$ is open is outlined in the edit to my answer. You can also easily draw the picture to that solution.